# Is the optocoupler placed before or after the gate driver?

Tags: opto-isolator, gate-driving

Is it

1. MCU - OPTOCOUPLER - GATE DRIVER - MOSFET

or

2. MCU - GATE DRIVER - OPTOCOUPLER

and why?

**EDIT** : it cannot provide enough power so it is used for signals therefore option 1.

Comment: Hint: the gate driver's purpose is to drive a "gate".

Comment: So number 1. is correct then, thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Option 1 is correct. The purpose of opto coupler is to electrically isolate the micro controller and driver circuits. Since micro controller i/o pin current driven capability limited to less than 100mA or less than that. So it can't able to drive the driver circuits. Opto coupler circuits consume less amount of current so it can be driven by micro controller. And also some times to meet the required voltage level to drive the gate driver.